# For loop, never ends

Tags: java

I am new to coding, I have been trying to make for loop with counter on, however the for loop is never ending, and I'm not sure why, please help. :) Thank you!

```
public class EvenOdd {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        int counter;


        counter = 0;
        for (double gallon = 1; gallon <= 10; counter ++ ) {
            double liter = gallon * 3.78541;
            System.out.println(gallon + "Gallon is equal to" + liter +"liter.");


                counter ++;
                if (counter == 5) {
                    System.out.println();
                    counter = 0 ;
            }
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: clue : what is the exit condition ?

Comment: Your loop variable `gallon` never change ! You have to replace `counter++` by `gallon++` for example.

Comment: @Lutzi Only in the for loop of course, which would be `for (double gallon = 1; gallon <= 10; gallon++ )`

Comment: The output you get should have been a really big hint! Notice how all values are the same, over and over again.

Comment: Your problem is you are looping whilst gallon<=10. nothing adjusts gallon.

Comment: @user12820261 What is the point of counter ?

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is gallon <= 10 . But you never increment gallon. You could change counter ++ to gallon++ ... or make a different change.

But only in the for loop "increment" part, not inside the loop body. As suggested by  Some programmer dude

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in this line:
`for (double gallon = 1; gallon <= 10; counter ++ ) {`

replace it with this line:
`for (double gallon = 1; gallon <= 10; gallon++ ) {`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to increment the value of `gallon` you can do it by:

```
        counter = 0;
        for (double gallon = 1; gallon <= 10; counter++, gallon++ ) {
        ...
```

Comment: I doubt OP wants to increment `counter` twice for every iteration.